# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Cursor is not connected

Tags: python, mysql, connector

after writing word on entry page  that i want to search and letters inside of word it goes to /search4 and i get error on page with **mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Cursor is not connected** after checking here is code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, escape
from vsearch import search4letters
from DBcm import UseDatabase

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['dbconfig'] = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
                            'user': 'vsearch',
                            'password': 'vsearchpasswd',
                            'database': 'vsearchlogDB', }

def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: str) -> None:
    with UseDatabase(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
        _SQL = """insert into log
                (phrase, letters, ip, browser_string, results)
                values
                (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    cursor.execute(_SQL, (req.form['phrase'],
                            req.form['letters'],
                            req.remote_addr,
                            req.user_agent.browser,
                            res, ))

@app.route('/search4', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> 'html':
    phrase = request.form['phrase']
    letters = request.form['letters']
    title = 'Here are your results:'
    results = str(search4letters(phrase, letters))
    log_request(request, results)
    return render_template('results.html',
                            the_title=title,
                            the_phrase=phrase,
                            the_letters=letters,
                            the_results=results,)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_template('entry.html',
                            the_title='Welcome to search4letters on the web!')

@app.route('/viewlog')
def view_the_log() -> 'html':
    with UseDatabase(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
        _SQL = """select phrase, letters, ip, browser_string, results
                  from log"""
        cursor.execute(_SQL)
        contents = cursor.fetchall()
    titles = ('Phrase', 'Letters', 'Remote_addr', 'User_agent', 'Results')
    return render_template('viewlog.html',
                            the_title='View Log',
                            the_row_titles=titles,
                            the_data=contents,)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cursor.execute` call should be inside the `with` block, because `cursor` only exists within that block.

It's literally a missing indentation:

```
def log_request(req: 'flask_request', res: str) -> None:
    with UseDatabase(app.config['dbconfig']) as cursor:
        _SQL = """insert into log
                (phrase, letters, ip, browser_string, results)
                values
                (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        cursor.execute(_SQL, (req.form['phrase'],
                            req.form['letters'],
                            req.remote_addr,
                            req.user_agent.browser,
                            res, ))
```